# R connection to SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, driver, rodbc

I have been trying to make a connection between R and the SQL server but I keep getting this error msg: 
 object 'C_RODBCDriverConnect' not found

It seems as if R is trying to find that object but is failing in doing so, anyone have an idea on how I can solve this issue? 
Reinstalling R is not an option as it's a work computer and I do not have the rights to do so. Also note that I am using the RODBC package as the odbc package doesn't want to install properly (I kept getting the zero non-exit error msg).

Thanks in advance.

Zachary

Comment: Please post code block with `library` lines and error/traceback that is raised on `odbcConnect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you make a **odbc connection in the odbc data sources** and ensure you have done it correctly to the sql server database.

```
library(RODBC)

#ODBC_1 refer to Database you want to use
con_ref = odbcConnect("name_of_connection")# name of connection is what you used in odbc connection setup


#input data
x <- sqlQuery(con_ref, "select * from db_name")
```

Comment: Hi Rishi, thanks for your reply. I still get the same error msg : Error in RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=SQL Server") : 
  object 'C_RODBCDriverConnect' not found

Comment: I think the problem here is you are making an instance in odbc that is not correct, can you add a screenshot of your configuration you did step by step.

Comment: Thanks Rishi, there was a problem with my computer rights at work. Problem solved and the connection has been made :)